# Kotlin lazy default property

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, how do i define a `var` that has a lazy default value ?

for example, a `val` would be something like this:

```
val toolbarColor  by lazy {color(R.color.colorPrimary)}
```

What i want to do is, have a default value for some property (`toolbarColor`), and i can change that value for anything else. Is it possible?

EDIT: This does the partial trick.

```
var toolbarColor = R.color.colorPrimary
    get() = color(field)
    set(value){
        field = value
    }
```

Is it possible to ease this by writing

```
var toolbarColor = color(R.color.colorPrimary)
    set(value){
        field = value
    }
```

in a way that the default value is computed lazily? At the moment it won't work because `color()` needs a `Context` that is only initialized later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own delegate method:

```
private class ColorDelegate<T>(initializer: () -> T) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {

    private var initializer: (() -> T)? = initializer

    private var value: T? = null

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return value ?: initializer!!()
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

Declare in some delegate:

```
object DelegatesExt {
    fun <T> lazyColor(initializer: () -> T): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> = ColorDelegate(initializer)
}
```

And use as follow:

```
var toolbarColor by DelegatesExt.lazyColor {
    // you can have access to your current context here.
    // return the default color to be used
    resources.getColor(R.color.your_color)
}

...

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // some fun code
    // toolbarColor at this point will be R.color.your_color
    // but you can set it a new value
    toolbarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.new_color)
    // now toolbarColor has the new value that you provide.
}
```

I think this could be a cleaner way to do, but I don't know yet (starting with kotlin few days ago). I will take a look and see if this could be done with less code.

Comment: ok thank you! That seems a lot of code for such an easy stuff. let's see if we can't find a better alternative tho, if not i'll acept ur ans

Comment: maybe it should be in stdlib?

Answer (score 1):

You can [store your property in a map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) to basically create a mutable lazy. You need a mutable map (like a `HashMap<K, V>`) with a default function to delegate to:

```
var toolbarColor by hashMapOf<String, Any?>()
        .withDefault { toolbarColor = R.color.colorPrimary; toolbarColor }
```

You'll also need to import some extension functions: `import kotlin.properties.getValue` and `import kotlin.properties.setValue`.

It would be nice if Kotlin provided something built-in and optimized for this (like a `mutableLazy` or something). As such, I've created [KT-10451](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10451).

Comment: Using hashmap like this, can I use context in initializer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "use context"?